# Fix SSH (client and server) on Mac OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: ssh, logging, mac

I have upgraded my Mac to Mountain Lion. Now that its complete I cannot SSH into any server for more than a few seconds, and I cannot receive any SSH connections.

I can only assume something from the upgrade has caused the issue. What can I do to diagnose the error and fix it? I would like to connect to other systems using the user name `jjasonclark` and I would like others to connect to my system with user name `remotepair`.

I don't have any logs about ssh in `/var/log/system.log`. I don't have a file called `/var/log/secure.log`. And `grep`ing through `syslog -d /var/log/asl` for ssh shows only those times I edited the `/etc/sshd_config` file.

When others try to connect to me (with the `-vvv` option) their client will hang on this message.

```
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
```

Example connection from my machine to others `ssh -vvv jjasonclark.analoganalytics.com`

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /usr/local/Cellar/openssh/5.9p1/etc/ssh_config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to jjasonclark.analoganalytics.com [184.106.115.234] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/Users/jjasonclark/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /Users/jjasonclark/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/jjasonclark/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/jjasonclark/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/jjasonclark/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/jjasonclark/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/jjasonclark/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3 pat OpenSSH_4*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "jjasonclark.analoganalytics.com" from file "/Users/jjasonclark/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /Users/jjasonclark/.ssh/known_hosts:37
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /Users/jjasonclark/.ssh/known_hosts:38
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 2 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
```

My `/etc/syslog.conf`

```
# Note that flat file logs are now configured in /etc/asl.conf

install.*                                               @127.0.0.1:32376
```

My `/etc/sshd_config`

```
Protocol 2
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
LogLevel INFO
PermitRootLogin no
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
ClientAliveInterval 120
ClientAliveCountMax 3
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
AllowUsers jjasonclark remotepair
```

My `/etc/ssh_config`

```
Host *
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    ServerAliveInterval 60
```

Comment: I executed the same ssh command on my Mountain Lion MacBook. More or less the same output, but it continues, after what you pasted here, with "debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 124/256" which presumably refers to a Diffie-Hellman key exchange. Just in case that is helpful ...

Comment: Yes, this is machine specific. I've tried on other computers on the same network and everything works fine. Only this 1 Mac has the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

It was a weird one to solve this issue. It turned out that I needed to reset my PRAM. It must have stored some details that needed to change with the upgrade.

Apple has a [article on how to reset the PRAM](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11243). You reboot and hold <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>opt</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> until you hear the a 2nd time.

Comment: Excellent!  Now click the checkmark next to this answer to mark it as solved.

Comment: I have to wait until tomorrow to accept my own answer. Website is preventing it.